# Error in IOS App - Expected Identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting an error in Xcode when adding some labelLoading code in the .m file.  Hoping someone can help me out and point out the error in the code.  Don't beat me up too bad as I am learning.  I just can't get past this error.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize viewWeb;
@synthesize labelLoading;
@synthesize tqwWeb;
@synthesize blogWeb;
@synthesize eventsWeb;
@synthesize resWeb;
@synthesize homeWeb;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
  [viewWeb setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [labelLoading setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [labelLoading setHidden:YES];
}


{      **This is where the error Expected identifier or "(" occurs**

[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/DC1/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];

[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *afullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/DC2";
    NSURL *aurl = [NSURL URLWithString:afullURL];
    NSURLRequest *arequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aurl];
    [tqwWeb loadRequest:arequestObj];


[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *bfullURL = @"http:/www.rtics.com/DC3/";
    NSURL *burl = [NSURL URLWithString:bfullURL];
    NSURLRequest *brequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:burl];
    [blogWeb loadRequest:brequestObj];

[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *cfullURL = @"https://www.rtics.com/DC4";
    NSURL *curl = [NSURL URLWithString:cfullURL];
    NSURLRequest *crequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:curl];
    [eventsWeb loadRequest:crequestObj];

[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *dfullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/DC5";
    NSURL *durl = [NSURL URLWithString:dfullURL];
    NSURLRequest *drequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:durl];
    [resWeb loadRequest:drequestObj];

[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *efullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/";
    NSURL *eurl = [NSURL URLWithString:efullURL];
    NSURLRequest *erequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:eurl];
    [homeWeb loadRequest:erequestObj];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setViewWeb:nil];
    [self setLabelLoading:nil];
    [self setWebView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];


}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: That's because you've added the contents of viewDidLoad's implementation, without ever adding the method. Also, why are you calling super so many times?

Comment: It looks like you've got some copy/paste issues or you've got something seriously wrong with your `viewDidLoad` method. You should only call `[super viewDidLoad]` once from `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line before your error should have `- (void)viewDidLoad` and you should only call `[super viewDidLoad]` once. Move anything in your other `viewDidLoad` to this new method and delete your other viewDidLoad.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{      **This is where the error Expected identifier or "(" occurs**

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [viewWeb setDelegate:self];  // Moved from previous viewDidLoad method

    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/DC1/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];

    NSString *afullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/DC2";
    NSURL *aurl = [NSURL URLWithString:afullURL];
    NSURLRequest *arequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aurl];
    [tqwWeb loadRequest:arequestObj];

    NSString *bfullURL = @"http:/www.rtics.com/DC3/";
    NSURL *burl = [NSURL URLWithString:bfullURL];
    NSURLRequest *brequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:burl];
    [blogWeb loadRequest:brequestObj];

    NSString *cfullURL = @"https://www.rtics.com/DC4";
    NSURL *curl = [NSURL URLWithString:cfullURL];
    NSURLRequest *crequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:curl];
    [eventsWeb loadRequest:crequestObj];

    NSString *dfullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/DC5";
    NSURL *durl = [NSURL URLWithString:dfullURL];
    NSURLRequest *drequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:durl];
    [resWeb loadRequest:drequestObj];

    NSString *efullURL = @"http://www.rtics.com/";
    NSURL *eurl = [NSURL URLWithString:efullURL];
    NSURLRequest *erequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:eurl];
    [homeWeb loadRequest:erequestObj];
}
```